# how to show all records that has f.ex 'C++' in set of languages

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a problem with showing record if in column values are in set.
[image: Photo of record in database]

My code looks like this but it only works if value is one language.

```
function showSets($db,$lang)
{
echo "dane z database: <br>";
$sq = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE Languages = '$lang'";
$result = $db -> select($sq,['FamilyName','Name','Age','Country','Email','Languages','Payment']);
echo $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   clients
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET($lang, languages)
```

**Side note:**
Using string interpolation with `$lang` like your snippet shows probably leaves your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.
You should probably use a [prepared statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.